# Getting a dark output when converting .exr sequence to .mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a 16bit .exr image sequence in an RGB colorspace. When I convert it to .mp4 using:

```
ffmpeg -start_frame 1100 -i input.$04d.exr output.mp4
```

The resulting .mp4 file is very dark.
I tried importing it to a video compositing software (like NUKE) and apply a linear lut, it looks correct. How can I do the same thing using ffmpeg?

Comment: Side note, per FFMPEG docs, -start_frame should be -start_number. see: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same result programmatically? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981864/ffmpeg-programming-assign-color-transfer-characteristics

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The EXR decoder has a parameter to assign color transfer characteristics.

For sRGB, it is

```
ffmpeg -apply_trc iec61966_2_1 -start_number 1100 -i input%04d.exr output.mp4
```

Other available values are

```
 bt709                        .D.V.... BT.709
 gamma                        .D.V.... gamma
 gamma22                      .D.V.... BT.470 M
 gamma28                      .D.V.... BT.470 BG
 smpte170m                    .D.V.... SMPTE 170 M
 smpte240m                    .D.V.... SMPTE 240 M
 linear                       .D.V.... Linear
 log                          .D.V.... Log
 log_sqrt                     .D.V.... Log square root
 iec61966_2_4                 .D.V.... IEC 61966-2-4
 bt1361                       .D.V.... BT.1361
 iec61966_2_1                 .D.V.... IEC 61966-2-1
 bt2020_10bit                 .D.V.... BT.2020 - 10 bit
 bt2020_12bit                 .D.V.... BT.2020 - 12 bit
 smpte2084                    .D.V.... SMPTE ST 2084
 smpte428_1                   .D.V.... SMPTE ST 428-1
```

Comment: i get Codec AVOption apply_trc (color transfer characteristics to apply to EXR linear input) specified for output file #0 (output.mp4) is not an encoding option.

Comment: perfect that's much better! however i get some artifacts in an area in my video where i have pure black..do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: Try `bt709` instead.

Comment: gives me the same result:/

Comment: Does it show up when you add `-c:v libx264rgb` (after `-i`) ? Also, post before and after screenshots.

Comment: i just tried it with a different .exr sequence and it worked! so i guess the problem was in the previous sequence itself. many thanks for your help!!

Comment: There's reports of FFmpeg having issues with PIZ compressed EXRs. Can you test that?

Comment: The problem wasn't the EXR compression (i think), when i looked at the problematic source more closely i noticed there was some data there exactly where the artifacts appeared. You couldn't see that data unless you increased the brightness since it was very faded. But apparently it was "intensified" due to the EXR->mp4 encoding and that's why it popped out in the output.

Comment: also quick question - what if i have 2 inputs?

Comment: 2 EXRs? Add the `apply_trc` before each.

Comment: This worked on my mac, but I get "option not found" on ubuntu server. Any advice?

Comment: Older version of ffmpeg.

Comment: Is there an easy way to update ffmpeg? Or do I have to recompile from scratch?

Answer (score 3):

With the latest version of ffmpeg (version git-2020-03-24):

- *start_frame* is replaced by *start_**number***
- $04d is replaced by %04d

I had to add the -vcodec argument to have the expected result.

```
ffmpeg -y -apply_trc iec61966_2_1 -start_number 1 -i input.%04d.exr  -vcodec mpeg4 output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of assumptions on what your source colorspace is in the exr file, you might want to use something like [oiiotool](https://openimageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oiiotool.html) and [OCIO](https://opencolorio.org/) if you have anything other than a straight linear rec709 colorspace.

Convert your colorspace to a 16-bit png before converting with ffmpeg.

See https://academysoftwarefoundation.github.io/EncodingGuidelines/Quickstart.html for more info.